# How to properly link a main function in assembly

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, ld, att

I have the following code in x86-64 AT&T assembly:

```
#42.s
#
#A really simple Hello World program.
#So simple it doesn't print anything.
#
#Compile as: gcc 42.s -z noexecstack -o 42
#Run as: ./42 ; echo $?

.global main
.type main function

.text

main:
  mov $42, %rax
  ret
```

This code can compile with the provided instructions `gcc 42.s -z noexecstack -o 42` and will compile fine. Executing `./42 ; echo $?` will return the expected `42`.

I wanted to do this but going step by step:

1. Assemble the code into an object file: `gcc -c 42.s -o 42.o`
2. Link the Object file (`42.o`) with the appropiate standard library. For this I tried `ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc 42.o -o 42`.

This manual approach does not work, because it does not makes an executable that starts with the `_start` function that will call my `main` function, as it does when simply relying completely on the compiler. Since it does not starts with the `_start` provided by the C standard library (I belive that's the library that provides that function), executing `ret` leads (correctly) to a segmentation fault.

How could I link the Object file (`42.o`) with the linker to get the same result as when I just use `gcc 42.s -z noexecstack -o 42`?

Edit: as suggested by Erik, I added all libraries including `crt` as part the their name. The command: `ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o -lc -z noexecstack  -e _start 42.o -o 42` succesfully linked my `42.o` object file so the `main` function returns to the `_start` one. I don't know if all those libraries are needed tough.

Comment: You also need to link the CRT startup files that pass a pointer to `main` to `__libc_start_main`.  Use `gcc -v 42.s` to see the commands it runs, including the linking step.  (`collect2` is just a wrapper for `ld` that AFAIK passes on all its args unchanged without adding any on GNU/Linux.)

Comment: `_start` has no where to return, so it must use a system call to end the process.  If you choose to start with `main` or anything else bypassing `_start` you'll have to do the same: exit the process via system call rather than returning. There's a linker option to use an alternate name rather than `_start`.

Comment: Dear Peter,

Looking at the output, I can see the following libraries starting/containing `crt`:

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o`
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o`
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o`
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o`
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o`

I don't know which should I add, maybe all? 

Kind regards.

Comment: Dear Peter:

I used `ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o -lc -z noexecstack  -e _start 42.o -o 42` and it worked perfectly. Do all those libraries are required?

Dear Erik:

The `_start` function would be the one in the standard library who calls my `main` function which returns to that one.